# Firebase Realtime Database - Issue with Updating Unread Messages Count and Unsubscribing Listeners

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm implementing 1:1 chatting on my Next.js website.

I'm encountering an issue with updating and properly unsubscribing listeners for unread messages count in Firebase Realtime Database. Here's the scenario:

I have a function `getUnreadMessages` that listens to changes in the database to calculate the total unread messages count for a user across multiple chats. The function sets up onValue listeners for each chat's unread messages count and accumulates the count. However, when I use another function `setUnreadMessages` to update the count for a specific chat, the listeners established by onValue do not update accordingly. This leads to outdated counts being returned by `getUnreadMessages`.

This is my firebase database structure

```
{
  "chats": {
    "-NsiGVfPascYlr1ukPVP": {
      "lastMessage": "sdf",
      "members": {
        "65dd85133a58aa82bc050081": true,
        "65e71757ff707f0da0b9e8d8": true
      },
      "timestamp": 1710242413808,
      "unreadMessages": {
        "65dd85133a58aa82bc050081": 0,
        "65e71757ff707f0da0b9e8d8": 5
      }
    },
    "one": {
      "lastMessage": "안녕",
      "members": {
        "65dd85133a58aa82bc050081": true,
        "65df0955c7a84d629f8a54a5": true
      },
      "timestamp": 1710220731677,
      "unreadMessages": {
        "65dd85133a58aa82bc050081": 0
      }
    }
  },
  "users": {
    "65dd85133a58aa82bc050081": {
      "chats": {
        "-NsiGVfPascYlr1ukPVP": true,
        "one": true
      }
    },
    "65df0955c7a84d629f8a54a5": {
      "chats": {
        "one": true
      }
    },
    "65e71757ff707f0da0b9e8d8": {
      "chats": {
        "-NsiGVfPascYlr1ukPVP": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
export async function getUnreadMessages({
  userId,
}: {
  userId: string;
}): Promise<number> {
  let totalUnreadMessages = 0;

  const userChatsRef = ref(realtimeDB, `users/${userId}/chats`);
  const snapshot = await get(userChatsRef);
  const chatIds = snapshot.val() || {};

  const promises: Promise<void>[] = [];

  for (const chatId in chatIds) {
    const userChatRefRef = ref(
      realtimeDB,
      `chats/${chatId}/unreadMessages/${userId}`
    );

    const promise = new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
      onValue(
        userChatRefRef,
        (snapshot: DataSnapshot) => {
          const unreadMessagesCount = snapshot.exists() ? snapshot.val() : 0;
          totalUnreadMessages += unreadMessagesCount;
          resolve();
        },
        (error) => {
          console.error(`Error listening to chat ${chatId}:`, error);
          reject(error);
        }
      );
    });

    promises.push(promise);
  }

  await Promise.all(promises);
  return totalUnreadMessages;
}
```

```
export async function setUnreadMessages({
  chatId,
  userId,
  isReset,
}: {
  chatId: string;
  userId: string;
  isReset?: boolean;
}): Promise<void> {
  if (!chatId || !userId) return;
  try {
    const unreadMessagesRef = ref(
      realtimeDB,
      `chats/${chatId}/unreadMessages/${userId}`
    );
    let unreadMessagesCount = 0;

    if (!isReset) {
      const unreadMessagesSnapshot = await get(unreadMessagesRef);

      if (unreadMessagesSnapshot.exists()) {
        unreadMessagesCount = unreadMessagesSnapshot.val() || 0;
      }
    }

    await set(
      unreadMessagesRef,
      isReset ? unreadMessagesCount : ++unreadMessagesCount
    );
    console.log(
      `Unread messages count for user ${userId} in chat ${chatId} reset.`
    );
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error resetting user unread messages count:", error);
    throw error;
  }
}
```

and I use react-query to fetch the data.

```
const { data: fetchedUnreadMessagesCount } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["unreadMessagesCount"],
    queryFn: () => getUnreadMessages({ userId: session?.user.id }),
    enabled: !!session?.user.id,
  });
```

My firebase version is `v10.8.1`.
Please tell me where I'm doing wrong? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **listen for realtime updates** to a value, you:

- Can't `return` that value, as a `return` statement can only run once.
- Can't use promises to do so, as a `Promise` can only resolve once.

If you want to listen for updates, that can happen multiple times - so you need to use a mechanism that allows that. This is in fact precisely why the `onValue` API takes a callback method, rather than returning a Promise. You'll need to do something similar.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your insight. My issue comes from my lack of knowledges about `onValue` and `Promise` as your feedback. I created a custom hook on this post. Could you take a look if there is any mistake in it?

Comment: Even if you're new to promises, does the first bullet point in my answer still make sense?

Answer (score 0):

I created a custom hook that listens the `onValue`

```
type UseUnreadMessagesCountType = {
  userId: string;
};

export default function useUnreadMessagesCount({
  userId,
}: UseUnreadMessagesCountType) {
  const [chats, setChats] = useState<Record<string, number> | null>({} || null);
  const { chatsId } = useMyChats();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!chatsId || !userId) return;
    let unsubscribeFunctions: Unsubscribe[] = [];

    const cleanup = () => {
      unsubscribeFunctions.forEach((unsubscribe) => unsubscribe());
    };

    unsubscribeFunctions = Object.keys(chatsId).map((chatId) => {
      const userChatRefRef = ref(
        realtimeDB,
        `chats/${chatId}/unreadMessages/${userId}`
      );

      const unsubscribe = onValue(
        userChatRefRef,
        (snapshot) => {
          const unreadMessagesCount = snapshot.exists() ? snapshot.val() : 0;
          setChats((prev) => ({
            ...prev,
            [chatId]: unreadMessagesCount,
          }));
        },
        (error) => {
          console.error(`Error listening to chat ${chatId}:`, error);
        }
      );

      return unsubscribe;
    });

    return cleanup;
  }, [chatsId, userId]);

  return sumObjectValues(chats);
}
```